# How many terms are needed to approximate wifhinv$0.01$

Tags: definite-integrals

> In a series expansion of given  definite Integration $$\int^{1}_{0}e^{-x^2}dx$$
>
> How many terms of this series are necessary to approximate this integral to within $0.01$

What i try:

$$\int^{1}_{0}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{n!}dx$$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int^{1}_{0}x^{2n}dx=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)n!}$$

Could some help me How many terms are used to approximate this integral within $0.01$

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you showed the integral is equal to:

$$\int_0^1\exp\left(-x^2\right)\space\text{d}x=\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}+1\right)\left(\text{n}!\right)}=\frac{\text{erf}\left(1\right)\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\approx0.746824132812427\tag1$$

Where $\text{erf}\left(x\right)$ is the [error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html).

So, you're trying to find:

$$\left|\int_0^1\exp\left(-x^2\right)\space\text{d}x-\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}+1\right)\left(\text{n}!\right)}\right|<\frac{1}{100}\tag2$$

Answer (score 1):

For an alternating series where the terms decrease in absolute value, the remainder (i.e., the error between the partial sum and the infinite sum) is always bounded by the absolute value of the next term left out of the partial sum. See [here](https://www.mathwords.com/a/alternating_series_remainder.htm) for instance.

You have calculated that the integral is equal to the alternating series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)n!}$, and so using the above fact you know:
\begin{align*}
\left| \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)n!} - \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)n!}\right| &\leq \frac{1}{(2N+1)N!}\\
\left|\int_0^1 e^{-x^2} \ dx - \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)n!}\right| &\leq \frac{1}{(2N+1)N!}\\
\end{align*}

So you just need to find the smallest $N$ so that $\frac{1}{(2N+1)N!} \leq 0.01$.